# complex matrices integration

Tags: calculus, integration, matrices, complex-analysis, gamma-function

I can't find a proof of the following fact:
$$
\int_0^{+\infty} H\, \exp(tF)\, G \exp(-st)\ dt = H(s\,I - F)^{-1}G 
$$

where $H,F,G$ are constant matrices, $s$ is complex such that $s\,I - F$ is invertible.

---

First I assume that the sens of this integral should be understood component by component.
I started to write complicated expression using the Gamma function: 
$$
\int_0^{+\infty} H\, \exp(tF)\, G e^{-st}\ dt 
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} H \frac{F^k}{k!} G\, \int_0^{\infty} t^k e^{-st}\ dt
\\
=...
$$
but with no conlusion

Comment: You can ignore $H$ and $G$ for a start, because if you can prove $$\int_0^{+\infty} \exp(tF) \exp(-st)\ dt = (s\,I - F)^{-1}$$ your result follows immediately.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: you are right of course. I deleted my second comment shortly after posting it, for this very reason.

Comment: Sufficient. The limit is also zero if for example $sI-F$ is nilpotent, even if it has negative eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $H,G$ are constant (and sums and limits are linear), you have 
$$
\int_0^{+\infty} H\, \exp(tF)\, G \exp(-st)\ dt=H\,\left(\int_0^{+\infty} \, \exp(tF)\,  \exp(-st)\ dt\right)\,G.
$$
Now 
$$
e^{tF}e^{-st}=e^{-(sI-F)t}
$$
As $sI-F$ is invertible, the antiderivative of $e^{-(sI-F)t}$ is $-(sI-F)^{-1}e^{-(sI-F)t}$.
Then
$$
\int_0^{m} \, \exp(tF)\,  \exp(-st)\ dt=\left.\vphantom{\int}-(sI-F)^{-1}e^{-(sI-F)t}\right|_{t=0}^{t=m}=(sI-F)^{-1}(I-e^{-(sI-F)m}).
$$
Now you want to take limit as $m\to\infty$. This doesn't always work. For instance, if $F=0$ and $s=-1$, the limit clearly doesn't exist. You need $F$ so satisfy some condition that guarantees that $\lim_{m\to\infty} e^{-(sI-F)m}=0$. This works for exampe if $sI-F$ is positive definite.